# Crontab Not Working with Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: windows, bash, ubuntu, cron, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to schedule a bash script to run with Bash on Ubuntu on Windows in Windows 10. Every time that I to write the cron, I get the following error messages in the terminal:

```
crontab: installing new crontab
/var/spool/cron/: mkstemp: Permission denied
crontab: edits left in /tmp/crontab.4q0z3i/crontab
```

Here is what the crontab entry looks like:

```
# m h  dom mon dow   command
27 10 * * * /home/admin/test.sh > /home/admin/logs/test.log 2>&1
```

What exactly is going on here?

Comment: Does your use have permissions to write in `/var/spool/cron`? Does your uses have permissions to use `cron`?

Comment: Hi @Jdamian, how do I check this? There is only one unix account set up in bash on my system.

Answer (score 51):

You need to add yourself to the crontab group.

```
usermod -a -G crontab (username)
```

Once you have done this, you also need to make sure that cron is running.  Usually this is started with `start cron` however upstart does not work on WSL from what I can tell, but `sudo cron` does the job.

One caveat to this is that once you close all bash windows, cron will stop running even though your computer runs.  However, as long as you have a bash window open and cron running, it will perform as expected.

Comment: This helped, Thanks!
One reminder for some people like me - Restart your bash session for this to take effect.

Comment: Also, if you want cron and other background jobs to keep running after you close all bash windows, you can use this vb script at start up, and it keeps a hiden instance of bash running.  https://gist.github.com/leonelsr/cde77574519eb1fd672bc9690e01257e

Comment: I've been using [wabash and its daemon](https://github.com/cerebrate/wabash) for this, but thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Using the script mentioned by jeffpkamp works great. To auto-start cron I added `sudo cron` to my ~/.bashrc file and `myuser ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/usr/sbin/cron` to my /etc/sudoers file.

Comment: 11101101b it asks for my password while starting bash on windows. Any workaround?

Comment: *"You need to add yourself to the crontab group."* It's not clear to me whether this is strictly necessary now in WSL on Windows 10. My WSL installation does have a group named "crontab". I'm *not* a member of that group, but I can edit my crontab, and start cron (sudo cron) without error. I suppose that could be because I'm a local admin on this laptop.

Answer (score 24):

To make sure cron is actually running you can type `service cron status`. If it isn't currently running then type `service cron start` and you should be good to go.

Comment: I think it's `service cron status` instead of `service status cron`

Comment: I wonder why even cron need to be started and as a service

Comment: @YakobUbaidi It likely has to do with background services not being available in general on WSL, such as `systemd`.

Answer (score 5):

There is workaround mentioned on the github bug for this one, can't seem to find it now!

```
sudo crontab -u $USER -e
```

Answer (score 3):

Run the command `sudo service cron start` and give password.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your crontab does have the setgid permission set like this,
`-rwxr-sr-x 1 root crontab 39024 May 5 2016 /usr/bin/crontab`

you should do `sudo chown <username> /usr/bin/crontab`

then `sudo chmod g+s /usr/bin/crontab`

You should be root to do all this.

Comment: Hi @Arduino Sentinel, still getting the same error message.

Comment: what is the output of this `ls -l /var/spool/cron/crontabs`

Comment: `ls: cannot open directory /var/spool/cron/crontabs: Permission denied`

Comment: did you run that with `sudo`?

Comment: Yes, when run without `sudo`, I got the following message: `chmod: changing permissions of ‘/var/spool/cron/crontabs’: Operation not permitted`

Comment: Though I don't believe that this made any difference because I just tried executing `crontab -e` again to change the script run time and I am still receiving the same error message. Should I reinstall Bash on Ubuntu on Windows?

Comment: no,don't rush,,one more thing,,what about `sudo ls -la /var/spool/cron/crontabs`

Comment: seems like `/usr/bin/crontab`doesn't  have the setgid permission set

Comment: The output is: `total 0
drwx-wx--T 2 root crontab 0 Feb  9  2013 .
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root    0 Sep 13 20:42 ..`

Comment: edited the answer,try that instead,and please give feedback

Comment: I just read somewhere that WSL doesn't support background processes. Is this why I am running into so many issues?

Comment: it looks that it might be also causing the problem,by the way am currently on linux,,,am installing win10 on vm right now so that i try it out!and by the way what is the output of `ls -al /usr/bin/crontab` now?

Comment: hey its seems the owner is `nbcufs` instead of `root`

Answer (score 0):

try to put this powershell command in a windows task and see what happens

```
bash -c "rsync -acAXvc --delete --numeric-ids /mnt/d/no_movies/* rsync://10.66.6.66/danielle_no_movies"
```

bash -c "command" means run this command using the linux subsystem bash shell

the command is "rsync --rsync_switches /mnt/windows_drive_letter/source_dir/* rsync://rsync_daemon_address/rsync_module"

i just came up with it and i'm still testing so i can't promise that it will actually work.

i am running it from a powershell window with no admin privileges right now and it is reporting that it is "sending the incremental file list". the task manager reports that there is an rsync process that is doing a lot of stuff with drive d:

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this ought to start Crontab once using tmux and have it live even if you close your bash session(see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/12/04/background-task-support-in-wsl/)). I haven't tried this yet (but will soon).

Answer (score 0):

crontab does not run under windows wsl.  Linux is not started with systemd

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -5):

WSL does not currently support background processes.

Comment: Can you kindly add a reference ?

Comment: It does now "Starting in Windows Insiders Build 17046, WSL supports background tasks (including daemons)" - [Background Task Support in WSL](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2017/12/04/background-task-support-in-wsl/)

Comment: It does, I have enabled cron and installed even MySql