# Crontab never executes in Windows Subsystem for Linux

Tags: bash, cron, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I set up some cronjobs a while back using `crontab -e`. My crontab includes the following line:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/touch /home/blah/MADEBYCRON
```

It's been weeks since I did this. I have never seen `/home/blah/MADEBYCRON`. I set permissions on my home directory so it should be able to create files in this directory, so why does this file never exist?

`/var/log/syslog` does not exist.

Comment: please share the syslog: `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`

Comment: Running cron on WSL seems to require some crazy hacks. There is no indication in your question that you have any such hacks in place. The least wacky I saw from quick google results amounted to turning WSL into a Windows service. (Not particularly precise I'm afraid; my recommended solution is always to ditch Windows.)

Comment: Did you manage to get this to work? I have an exact similar problem; I start atd and cron both manually on every restart, but the cron jobs never execute. In my case I noticed when I was upgrading some packages, the cron started working. However on next reboot it was back to the same situation.

Comment: Hi, I found this https://scottiestech.info/2018/08/07/run-cron-jobs-in-windows-subsystem-for-linux/ but its a kinda hacking and requires very very big effort .. :/

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Ensure that the cron service is running. I use WSL with cron every day for my local backups using rsync so this should work.

Use `which cron` to check its installed, mine says `/usr/sbin/cron`.

Use `crontab -l` to list your configured jobs.

Use `ps aux | grep cron` to look see if cron is running, you should see `/usr/sbin/cron` if it is.

Use `service cron status` to check if the service is started.

Use `sudo service cron start` to start the cron service if it is not running.

Comment: so after running the start command there is still no cron process nor does the status check say anything useful.

Comment: This worked for me, figured the service hadn't been started

Comment: @Damo That worked for me, but now it doesn't log anything. The file `/var/log/cron.log` is empty file) and `/var/log/syslog` has no entries about cron.

Comment: I solved the log issue updating the conf /etc/rsyslog.d/50-default.conf, see https://serverfault.com/a/470938/321667 and then restarting rsyslog  `sudo service rsyslog restart`

Comment: `Use ps aux | grep cron to look see if cron is running`. And if it isn't running, then go to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41281112/crontab-not-working-with-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windows. This worked for me with Pengwin (Ubuntu based) in WSL 2.

Answer (score 3):

Since WSL is not starting services on startup you also need to start `rsyslog` before starting cron if you want to see the `cron` logs in `/var/log/syslog`:

```bash
sudo service rsyslog start
sudo service cron start
```

Then view logs

```bash
grep -i cron /var/log/syslog
```

`syslog` only has the information which script was run and when. If you want to see the output of the script you need to redirect it to a file, e.g. like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/touch /home/blah/MADEBYCRON >> /home/blah/cron_output.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 2):

Under recent WSL releases, you can enable Systemd support as mentioned in this [Community Wiki answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73833858/11810933).  With Systemd, the `cron` service (unit) should automatically be started when you start your WSL distribution.

Note that Systemd is not required under WSL, and may add additional, unneeded overhead.  Consider using one of the other existing answers if you don't need Systemd support.

Answer (score 1):

You need to start the `cron` service. Services do note start automaticaly on WSL as ist does not use `systemd`. The easyest way to do this is to add the following line to your `.bashrc`:

`service cron status || sudo service cron start`

On the first start you will need to enter the `sudo` password and you will see somthing like this

[image: start cron service]