# crontab not running on WSL2

Tags: cron, wsl-2

I'm trying to automate a task with python, but contrab seems to not work properly on my WSL2 environment. I've already manually turned it on using `sudo service cron start`, and even though `service cron status` says it is running, it still seems to not work.

To check it out, I've set it to run a simpler script every 2 minutes to see if it was an issue with python itself, but the issue persists. Below is my cron setting:

```
*/2 * * * * /home/viper/example.sh
```

and the actual code inside the bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "Hello World - Generated every 2 mins" >> ~/hello1.txt
```

I tried googling around any possible fixes but neither of them worked.

Comment: That's strange. Not sure what would cause that. Do any of the suggestions in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60256901/crontab-never-executes-in-windows-subsystem-linux) provide helpful debugging info?

Comment: Yes, I followed all the steps provided in the answer. It says that crontab is running but it still doesn't do anything.